# how to give access to specific dashboard to a certain user in analytics dashboard wso2?

Tags: wso2, analytics, wso2-api-manager

I want to do these steps :
1.define a new user in carbon
2.create a new dashboard in analytics as carbon super user
3.give access to created dashboard to defined user
how can I do this ?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [this](https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/3.2.0/learn/analytics/managing-dashboard-permissions/) document which explains how to manage permissions for different dashboards.